# Set focus to a special component

Tags: swing, haxe, setfocus

I have a class Dialog that encapsulates window of type `org.aswing.Component`.
I've create function `focus()` this way:

```
public function focus() {
    if (Std.is(window, org.aswing.Component)) {
        var b = window.requestFocus();
    } 
}
```

After executing this function `b` is true (i.e. reqest is valid) but no event hadlers was fired. Can you explain how to force focus setting?

Answer (score 0):

Containers(including JWindow) cannot be focused. To find out whether component can be focused or not, you should use something like the following

```
trace(component.isFocusable());
```

Take a closer look at http://doc.aswing.org/a3/

Answer (score 0):

When you create the JWindow you can pass in modal=true which will ensure that the JWindow is always on top and prevent users from accessing components in other JWindows. You can also call the setModal() method of JWindow after you have created it.